# How To Retun Output Paramater From Stored Procedure

Tags: sql, sql-server

I would like to have the total row count as the output parameter, which will later be accessed from C#. This query gives an error - Invalid object name 'TBL'

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[GetOrderDetails]
    @SortOrder nchar(10), 
    @ColName nvarchar(20),          
    @StartIndex int,
    @PageSize int,
    @RecordCount int output
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

  DECLARE @Query nvarchar(MAX), 
          @Params nvarchar(MAX)

  SET @StartIndex = (@PageSize * (@StartIndex-1))+1
  SET @PageSize = @StartIndex + @PageSize - 1

  SET @Params = '@StartIndex int,
                 @PageSize int,
                 @RecordCount int'

  SET @Query = 'WITH TBL AS
                (
                 SELECT OD.OrderID,OD.ProductID,P.ProductName,OD.UnitPrice,
                 OD.Quantity,OD.Discount
                 FROM [Order Details] OD
                 LEFT JOIN Products P ON OD.ProductID = P.ProductID
                )

                SELECT @RecordCount = COUNT(*) FROM TBL ;

                SELECT * FROM
                (
                 SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY '+@ColName+')Row, * 
                 FROM TBL
                )TEMP
                WHERE Row BETWEEN @StartIndex AND @PageSize
                ORDER BY Row '+@SortOrder

  execute sp_Executesql @Query,@Params,@RecordCount,@StartIndex,@PageSize
END
```

Answer (score 1):

You are using **Common Table Expression** named **`TBL`** which is availaible till next SQL statement from its definition and is lost to further SQL statement.

Since you have already used `TBL` once in

```
 SELECT @RecordCount = COUNT(*) FROM TBL ;
```

it is now lost and is not availaible subsequently in next SQL statement of your dynamic query and gives error: **`Invalid Object named TBL`**

```
SELECT * FROM
                (
                 SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY '+@ColName+')Row, * 
                 FROM TBL
                )TEMP
                WHERE Row BETWEEN @StartIndex AND @PageSize
```

You can try this

```
SET @Query = ';WITH TBL AS
                (
                 SELECT OD.OrderID,OD.ProductID,P.ProductName,OD.UnitPrice,
                 OD.Quantity,OD.Discount
                 FROM [Order Details] OD
                 LEFT JOIN Products P ON OD.ProductID = P.ProductID
                )

                --SELECT @RecordCount = COUNT(*) FROM TBL ; Remove this statement

                SELECT * FROM
                (
                 SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY '+@ColName+')Row,
                         @RecordCount = COUNT(*) , * 
                 FROM TBL
                )TEMP
                WHERE Row BETWEEN @StartIndex AND @PageSize
                ORDER BY Row '+@SortOrder
```

Comment: Incorrect syntax near '='.. Also, it's still an o/p param right?

Answer (score 1):

You could use a table variable rather than a CTE, that way you can count then select as you see fit.
If you do this you need to fix your execute call:

```
  execute sp_Executesql 
    @Query,
    @Params,
    @StartIndex,
    @PageSize,
    @RecordCount OUTPUT
```

as the order is currently incorrect and your missing an `OUTPUT`.

Alternatively you could remove the output param and return the total count as a column in your second select;

```
SELECT * FROM
(
   SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY '+@ColName+') Row
   , *
   , COUNT(*) OVER() AS TOTAL_ROWS
```